# VisualVM Sampling & Accuracy

Tags: java, profiling

It's been said in other questions that [jvisualvm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualVM) sampling works as a "lightweight" profiling tool by calculating metrics directly from Java stack frames.

Its almost unanimously agreed that such a technique is *faster* but not as *accurate* in terms of its "timings". My question: why is this method not as accurate? And, what is it not as accurate as (as opposed to what? Are there more precise profiling techniques?)?

Comment: When the goal is to find speedup opportunities (as opposed to just general measurements) it's a mistake to assume that accuracy of timing and metrics are important. *[More on that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)*

Comment: It's like a doctor looking for a tumor in a CT scan. He doesn't find it by measuring. He finds it by looking. Then he can measure it if he wants to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few factors I am aware of:

1. Look at the javadoc of `System.currentTimeMillis()` and note what it says about the Operating System granularity.  For even more fun, look at the source code of that method and see how it rounds to a millisecond. A similar rule applies for  Java's nanosecond support, look at the source code to see how it is actually used and you might be surprised.
2. There are still gaps where there are no Java APIs to measure certain things, e.g.  Clock counters on a CPU (which we're working on with [jpcm](http://java.net/projects/jpcm/)) and APIs into the running GC itself.

HTH a little.